# Minimal application in Intellij platform

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eclipse-rcp, intellij-plugin

Is it possible to build a stripped down application using the Intellij platform, like [in this Eclipse RCP tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#wizward_launch)? I am aware that it is recommended to use this platform only for IDEs and I am willing to stick to this, but I would like to limit the user to only able to use features I approve, and also forbid to eg. import a maven project.

Answer (score 2):

I can just assume that [IntelliJ Platform](http://www.jetbrains.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983889) is what you describe. The documentation is not great though. IntelliJ is open sourced, so you can adjust it for your needs as far as the license permits.

Comment: You'll also have to prevent people from installing plugins, if you want to forbid maven projects... good luck with that :)